# Basic Authentication repeats when downloading a file in IE

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, internet-explorer-8, basic-authentication

i have a site using Basic Authetication, tied to our Active Directory. everything works fine, except in IE8 when i click on a link to download a file the authetication windows pops up again. i can cancel and it lets me download it with no problem.

why is it repeating since i am already authenticated? is there a way to get rid of it? I am unable to replicate it on any other browser. can't seem to find anything online. anyone else ran into this?

Comment: _any other browser_ includes IE9 or higher?

Comment: i tried, ie10 and it works fine, have not tried IE9

Comment: Check what's really happening (headers + requests traveling) with fiddler. Maybe browsers don't act the same after authentication... This is the fastest way to figure it out, everything else is just guessing.